# How to access array value inside an object in actionscript 3?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash, object

I have an object to specify animal's properties in Actionscript 3 :

```
var Rabbit:Object = {
    food : "Carrot",
    predator : ["Lion","Eagle","Human"]
};
```

and by calling `Rabbit['predator']` will give output `Lion,Eagle,Human`.

I want to access specific index of that `predator` array (like `predator[1]`) inside object `Rabbit` and store it inside a variable. But calling `Rabbit['predator'[1]]` or `Rabbit[predator[1]]` doesn't give me any desired output. How can I access it?

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Please accept the answer (click the tick mark below the voting buttons) if it helped you solve the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access your array inside the object like this:

```
var arr:Array = Rabbit.predator as Array;
trace(arr[1]);
```

Or you can also do:

```
Rabbit.predator[1];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much! I really forgot about dot syntaxes... It really helped me a lot

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to vote and accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var name:String = Rabbit.predator[0];  // Lion
var name:String = Rabbit["predator"][1];  // Eagle
```

You might consider having all properties of the Rabbit as Arrays so that you can always treat its "qualities" as a set of values.  I've made it rabbit below.  For example,

```
var rabbit:Object =
{
    food: ["Carrot"],
    predator: ["A", "B", "C"]
};
```

...and then you can...

```
for ( var key:String in rabbit )
{
    trace( key );
    var vals:Array = rabbit[key];
    for ( var i:int = 0; i < vals.length; ++i )
    {
        trace( "   ", vals[i] );
    }
}
```

It's convention for Javascript variables to start with lowercase, and classes to start with uppercase.  So, in your code, consider using rabbit instead of Rabbit.